# How to spy MockNgRedux in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, redux

I have this test case, where I am spying on ***NgRedux.getState()*** and returning value but looks like this is not getting spied and returning an expected value. Can anyone help me to understand where I have done wrong?

***test.spec.ts***

```
it('Redux should get called', () => {
   getMockObject();
   expect(MockNgRedux.getInstance().getState).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
    
const getMockObject = () => {
    initializeTestBed();
    spyOn(MockNgRedux.getInstance(), 'getState').and.callFake(() => {
        return {
            'documentSearch': {
                'searchPayload': {
                 // here mock values
                }
            }
        };
    });
};
    
const initializeTestBed = () => {
MockNgRedux.reset();

// Configure test component
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
        // Components
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NgRedux,
            useFactory: MockNgRedux.getInstance
        },
        BaseRequestOptions,
        
        // Providers
    ],
    imports: [
        NgReduxTestingModule,
    ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
    .overrideComponent(DocumentSearchResults, {
        set: {
            providers: [
             // Some providers
            ]
        }
    }).compileComponents();

TestBed.overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
    set: {
        entryComponents: [ // Some Entry Components]
    }
});
    
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DocumentSearchResults);
componentRef = fixture.componentInstance;

let searchResult = {
        "docsList": [
            // Mock Data
        ],
        "totalDocsFound": 2
    };

    const searchResultStub = MockNgRedux.getSelectorStub(['documentSearch', 'searchResults']);
    searchResultStub.next(searchResult);
    searchResultStub.complete();
    fixture.detectChanges();
};
```

***The problem in this code, When this test is running and when **NgRedux.getState()** is called then mocked values are not returning.***